# How to do this swipe view in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, swipe

How can I do this swipe in android? This is the android 5 app settings activity.

[image: App Settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `ViewPager` to achieve this. You can also add tabs like in this example.

Refer to :

[Creating Swipe Views with Tabs](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html)

[ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a `ViewPager` with a `RecyclerView`.

There are a lot of available libraries in github:

https://github.com/eccyan/SpinningTabStrip

https://github.com/lsjwzh/RecyclerViewPager

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator

You can check a few more here:

http://snowdream.github.io/awesome-android/#Menu